# How to use Ruby Java Bridge with threads (Sidekiq)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, sidekiq, rjb

I wrote a small Java class to read embedded images from an xls file and would need to use it in a background process (using Sidekiq) of my Ruby on Rails application. But it looks like there is some issues with threading as the JVM throws an error `guarantee(get_thread() == thread) failed: must be the same thread, quickly` when the sidekiq process starts executing the method where the Rjb is used.

This is how I set it up.

I wrote an initializer to set up the the rjb

```
require 'rjb'

JARS = Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/lib/java_libs/*.jar").join(':')
Rjb::load(JARS)
EXCEL_IMAGE_READER = Rjb::import('tools.ImageReader')
```

Then I use it in my background process

```
  def get_excel_images
    p 'Starting to get the images'
    images = []
    image_reader = EXCEL_IMAGE_READER.new(@excel_path)
    image_reader.get_file_names.each do |file_name|
      images << Attachment.new_from_bytes(image_reader.get_file(file_name), file_name)
    end
    images
  end
```

But as soon as the method is started to execute the JVM throws an exception. Here is the log from Sidekiq.

```
2014-10-30T09:47:02Z 11748 TID-17e7qk INFO: Running in ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [i686-linux]
2014-10-30T09:47:02Z 11748 TID-17e7qk INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2014-10-30T09:47:02Z 11748 TID-17e7qk INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
2014-10-30T09:47:31Z 11748 TID-19393k Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass JID-08eac9ed686f8d6146cda67f INFO: start
"Starting to get the images"
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (threadLocalStorage.cpp:60), pid=11748, tid=2960567104
#  guarantee(get_thread() == thread) failed: must be the same thread, quickly
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b32) (build 1.7.0_65-b32)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86 )
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.5.3
# Distribution: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, package 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/mika/projects/my_project/hs_err_pid11748.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried to move the stuff from the initializer into the `get_excel_images` method but it didn't have any effect. The code works if I run it directly from console or through an rspec test.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I would suggest moving the update to your answer, and accept your answer. IMO I would close this question, but there is no clear flag for it. While you have a detailed Q, the answer was short -- change to an implementation of Ruby that supports Java. I think, by now, most people would go straight to JRuby if wanting to add Java to their project.

Comment: Well. I have just recently switched back to MRI Ruby and moved all the java stuff into an independent daemon process. Ruby and the daemon are communicating through a TCP socket. I got frustrated with the slowness of JRuby. Now with MRI Ruby it is again a pleasure to develop my app.

Comment: I would suggest updating your answer with that comment, explaining why you chose JRuby then switched back to MRI. Include your "update" in your answer and remove it from the question. Show code, if possible, in your answer. Then accept it to "complete" this Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some information from Rjb Github issues https://github.com/arton/rjb/issues/24. It looks like downgrading to ruby 1.9.3 and rjb 1.4.9 might solve the issue, but it is not a good solution since ruby 1.9.3 is going to receive security patches only for a couple of months more. The issue being the how threads are created and how it has changed from ruby 1.9.3 to ruby 2.

After trying many different solutions I moved to JRuby. Now java interactions work easily.

UPDATE:

After suffering a year for the slowness of JRuby I moved all my Java stuff into an independent daemon process and communicate with the daemon through a TCP Socket using JSON to transmit the data. Now I'm back in MRI Ruby and the development feels enjoyable again.